# Uninstalling a Program via Powershell

Tags: powershell, uninstallation

I'm trying to uninstall some software via Powershell, and bumping into some issues. As im a complete noob, I'm piecing this together with trial and error.

**Script I'm running**

```
 ##################
    $appName = 'Automox'
    ##################

    # Get all entries that match our criteria. DisplayName matches $appname, DisplayVersion less than current
    $installed = @(Get-ChildItem $uninstReg -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object { ($_.DisplayName -match $appName) })
    
    # Initialize an array to store the uninstalled app information
    $uninstalled = @()

    # Start a loop in-case you get more than one match, uninstall each.
    foreach ($version in $installed) {
        #For every version found, run the uninstall string
        $uninstString = $version.UninstallString
        #If exe run as written + silent argument, if msiexec run as msi using the name of the reg key as the msi guid.
        if ($uninstString -match 'msiexec') {
            $process = Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/x $($version.PSChildName) /qn REBOOT=ReallySuppress" -Wait -PassThru
        } else {
            $process = Start-Process $uninstString -ArgumentList '/S' -Wait -PassThru
        }
        
        # Check exit code for success/fail
        # Using 3 "-eq" statements becuase older PowerShell doesn't support "-in"
        # If unsuccessful, don't add to uninstalled list.
        if ( ($process.ExitCode -eq '0') -or ($process.ExitCode -eq '1641') -or ($process.ExitCode -eq '3010') ) {
            $uninstalled += $version.PSPath
        }
    }
    
    return $uninstalled
}


$uninstalledApps = & "$env:SystemRoot\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command $scriptblock

# Use Write-Output so you can see a result in the Activity Log
Write-Output "$uninstalledApps"

if ($uninstalledApps) {
    Exit 0
} else { Exit 1 }
```

**Here's the error I'm getting**

```
At line:31 char:1
+ }
+ ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Comment: The error says the `}` just below line `return $uninstalled` shouldn't be there. Why not remove it then? Or is this just part of a larger script you incompletely copied from somewhere ? (I guess so, because now you are using an undefined variable `$uninstReg`)

Comment: @Theo OP forgot to copy-paste a line at the top that should have said `$scriptBlock={param($uninstreg)`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes, probably so